# Listen for HTTPS requests to port 3000 on EC2 for nodejs express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https

I have a nodejs app that uses express to listen on 3000 for requests like so:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.listen(3000, function () {
   console.log('Running on port 3000')
});
```

This works for HTTPS requests when I run the server locally with ngrok. But when running the nodejs app on EC2 I cannot hit this port through HTTPS. I have the security group for my instance setup as follows:

[image]

I can hit port 3000 on plain HTTP but not HTTPS, anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You have to enable HTTPS on your express.js server.

Comment: Cool, can I get HTTPS traffic into my application without a certificate? I am just running this application off AWS so I do not have a domain

Comment: You can read about Aws CloudFront

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MattTheHack, by default I believe Express listens via an HTTP Server. There are two things you can do here, the first being deploying your node express app as an HTTPS server, which requires the proper keys to get set up.

Something like the following:

```
var express = require('express')
var fs = require('fs')
var https = require('https')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
}, app)
.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000! Go to https://localhost:3000/')
})
```

This is not really recommended because then node is decrypting all the HTTPS traffic.

The recommended solution would be to place NGINX or some other routing tool on the server as well. You can then treat NGINX as a Proxy and allow NGINX to do the decryption for you. Your node app can still listen to port 3000 as an HTTP server, and NGINX simply redirects HTTPS port 443 traffic to localhost:3000

nginx.conf

```
http {
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate      "PATH_TO_CERT";
    ssl_certificate_key  "PATH_TO_CERT_KEY";

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  }
}
```

I would definitely recommend the second approach! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much! Can I get HTTPS traffic into my application without a certificate? I am just running this application off AWS so I do not have a domain

Comment: You will need a cert and key, that is just part of how HTTPS works. If this is for your testing only and you don't have a domain, you can generate your own certificate and key for free. Check out the following site, this will give you a short lived 90 day certificate for free: https://letsencrypt.org/  There are other means to generating these as well.This process is a little intense, so I don't want to go into full detail, but hopefully you should be able to follow along and this was enough guidance to get you started